# Visual Studio 2010 - Debug DLL - Debug Command using rundll32 doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, rundll32

I have a problem debugging a C++ DLL project in Visual Studio 2010. While debuging I want the DLL to be loaded by rundll32.exe automatically. To do so I follow these steps (like here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c91k1xcf.aspx):

1. In Solution Explorer, I select the project that creates the DLL.
2. From the View menu, I choose Property Pages.
3. In the Property Pages dialog box, I open the Configuration Properties folder and select the Debugging category.
4. In the Command box, I type: "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe"
5. In the Command Arguments box I type (main is the function to be executed): output.dll, main
6. In the Working Directory I type: $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)
7. Attach -> yes

After following these steps, I try to debug the DLL, but I get this error:

*"Unable to attach. Process "C:/Windows/System32\rundll32.exe" is not running on "MY-PC", Refresh the process list before attempting another attach."*

Anyone know how to debug a DLL, without manually starting rundll32.exe from command prompt and manually attaching to this process?

Answer (score 4):

You should set:

"Attach -> no"

otherwise the VS is not trying to start new rundll32.exe process.
Setting Attach -> yes tells VS to attach to existing process.